# Send Command.Value via Javascript to codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am fairly new to ASP.Net and I am stuck.
If my Hyperlink is clicked a Command.Value should be sent to the server. After getting that Command.Value the code behind should check if it is right and redirect to a specific site otherwise just reload the page.
Here is my Hyperlink:

```
<asp:HyperLink 
ID="Link" 
runat="server" 
Visible="true" 
NavigateUrl="javascript:document.FormServer.Command.value = 
'test';document.FormServer.submit();"
>Test!!</asp:HyperLink>
```

First of all I want to ask if my Hyperlink is right. Furthermore I am a bit stuck on the code behind regarding where I need to insert my `If` statement.

Comment: document.FormServer doesn't sound familiar. Assuming there's a form called "FormServer" then you could be doing something like document.forms["FormServer"].submit(); but document.FormServer.Command.value is unbeknownst to me. Can you post your asp.net form please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's much easier to send a parameter by GET in the url of your link. But if for any reason you want to do it by post and using javascript then try this.

**Web form:** param1 is a hidden field which value will be set using Javascript. When the form is submitted the hidden field is posted with the form.

```
<form id="FormServer" runat="server" >
    <input type="text" id="param1" name="param1" style="display:none;" />
    <div>
        <asp:HyperLink 
        ID="Link" 
        runat="server" 
        Visible="true" 
        NavigateUrl="javascript:document.getElementById('param1').value = 'test';document.forms['FormServer'].submit();"
        >Test!!</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string param1Value = Request["param1"];
    if (param1Value == "test")
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    else if(param1Value == "lost")
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

In the code behind it might be useful to check **this.IsPostBack**. That tells you why the page is being loaded. If it's because the link was clicked then IsPostBack will be true.

Comment: It seems neat, there is just one Problem: ASP.net has already a form in the master.page and dosn't allow a 2nd form in a child.page :/

Comment: Fixed this Problem through giving the Master.Site-Form the id "FormServer" now it works.